# Kestrel: Invoke-WebRequest doesn't work while the URL works in browser?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

### Update:

The following error only occur when launching the application using Kestrel.

I already added the following two lines for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate`

```
// in public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

// in public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
app.UseAuthentication();
```

---

I created a new test Asp.Net core Web API project (with **Windows authentication**) using Visual Studio 2019. And run it in Visual studio and a browser popped up with json returns shown.

Then I open a Powershell window and tested the url. It got the following error?

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I found the `ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate`.

```
PS C:\> ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? Subject -eq 'CN=localhost' | fl

Subject      : CN=localhost
Issuer       : CN=localhost
Thumbprint   : 7A16573FF2DBA47695B8CA15916D445C9361F255
FriendlyName : ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate
NotBefore    : 12/6/2019 4:45:04 PM
NotAfter     : 12/5/2020 4:45:04 PM
Extensions   : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid,
               System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
```

And it still got the error?

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast -CertificateThumbprint 7A16573FF2DBA47695B8CA15916D445C -UseDefaultCredentials
9361F255
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast -Certificate ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: is it supposed to be http or https?

Comment: This is likely just hiding a certificate validation error.

Comment: I've updated the question with cert parameter.

Comment: can you try `Invoke-RestMethod https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast -CertificateThumbprint 7A16573FF2DBA47695B8CA15916D445C9361F255 ` ?

Comment: @CodeRunner, `Invoke-RestMethod` got the same error.

Comment: can you try replacing localhost with IP address?

Comment: I've updated the question for IP address. The errors are different

Comment: how is your application hosted? IISExpress, WebAppName hosted , IIS or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. I am able to read it from the web api. 
Give it try with Invoke-RestMethod with -Certificate $cert as parameter.

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\4E1E5F6B5BAD49B13521C2DF12275C37E126DBB9
$response = Invoke-RestMethod https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast -Certificate $cert
Write-Host $response.Count
```

[image]

Comment: I still get the same error by using `-certificate`. I just run the newly created project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Now `Invoke-RestMethod https://localhost:44334/weatherforecast -Certificate $cert -UseDefaultCredentials` works after I change the visual studio using IIS Express.(Kestrel got the error)